# insert or update raw datatype in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, raw

I have a source database and I should insert or update some rows in another DB based on my source DB.
My Problem is when updating or inserting raw datatypes, just half of row value comes in target DB.

my raw part of code is:

```
v_raw                                        RAW(16);
FOR i IN 1 .. v_col_cnt
            LOOP
                CASE v_desc_tab ( i ).col_type
                    WHEN 1
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_namevar, v_desc_tab ( i ).col_max_len );
                    WHEN 2
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_numvar );
                    WHEN 12
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_datevar );
                    WHEN 96
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_charvar, v_desc_tab ( i ).col_max_len );
                    WHEN 112
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_clob );
                    WHEN 23
                    THEN
                        DBMS_SQL.define_column ( v_cursor_id, i, v_raw, v_desc_tab ( i ).col_max_len );
                    ELSE
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('another type');
                END CASE;
            END LOOP;



WHILE DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows ( v_cursor_id ) > 0
            LOOP
                v_insert_str := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_table_name || ' VALUES(' ;
                v_update_str := 'UPDATE ' || v_table_name || ' SET ';
                v_update_where_str := ' WHERE ';
                FOR i IN 1 .. v_col_cnt
                LOOP
                    CASE v_desc_tab ( i ).col_type
                    WHEN 23
                        THEN
                            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE ( v_cursor_id, i, v_raw );
                            v_insert_str := v_insert_str || '''' || v_raw || '''' || ', ';
                            IF is_index(v_table_name, v_desc_tab ( i ).col_name) != 1
                            THEN
                                v_update_str := v_update_str || v_desc_tab ( i ).col_name || ' = ''' || v_raw || '''' || ', ';
                            ELSE
                                v_update_where_str := v_update_where_str || v_desc_tab ( i ).col_name || ' = ''' || v_raw || '''' || ' and ';
                            END IF;
                    END CASE;
                END LOOP;
```

and after creating insert or update command, it will be updated or inserted.

for example a value in my source DB is: 0022F12C24984AECA5E529C533B067B3

but in Target it comes like : 0022F12C24984AEC

I tried  RAW(32) and  RAW(64) but it didn't work.

Comment: Do not pass values via concatenation, use bind variables. With bind variables the data is passed as the data, not as string representation of it

Comment: can you please tell me how can I do it in this example?

Comment: `execute immediate 'insert into some_table (some_raw_column) values(:1)' using your_raw_variable`. But it would be better to generate `insert all` statement and pass a collection to it

Comment: thank you, but I cant do it because I don't know exactly data come from which table and how many records I have. Every thing is dynamic and I should create insert or update based on loop.

Comment: [`DBMS_SQL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html): `OPEN_CURSOR` -> `PARSE` -> `EXECUTE`. Then `BIND_VARIABLE` for single value or `BIND_ARRAY` if you will build dynamic PL/SQL block and use `forall`